# Use node module in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm writing an app, and I want to use node module

```
js-golden-hour
```

I have no idea, how should I begin with, but I guess, that in my React component I should use something like this ( I have to pass zipCode to that module ) 
(react GoldenHour.js)

```
state = {
        postalCode: this.props.postalCode
    };

    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/goldenHour/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                postalCode: this.state.postalCode
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
              if( res.status === 200){
                  res.json()
                      .then( res => {
                          console.log(res.morning);
                      })
              }else{
                  const error = new Error(res.error);
                  throw error;
              }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
```

But this is as far as I can go, I'm stuck. In my node api folder I created route and have (goldenHours.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const GoldenHourCalc = require('js-golden-hour');

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if(res){
        const goldenHour = new GoldenHourCalc(req.body.postalCode);
        const morning = goldenHour.goldenHourMorning();
        const evening = goldenHour.goldenHourEvening();

        return res.status(200).json({
            morningStart: morning.start,
            morningEnd: morning.end,
            eveningStart: evening.start,
            eveningEnd: evening.end
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I can see that goldenHour is receiving postalCode properly, but when I try to console.log any data from that request in console it says only "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this api call to `componentDidMount()`, also are you getting proper response on hitting the api from `postman?` If you are using this as a middleware then you need to also call the `next()` function.